# Why does Wolfram say this symmetric matrix has complex eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

According to [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5B%7B%7B1%2BPower%5By%2C2%5DPower%5Bz%2C2%5D%2CxyPower%5Bz%2C2%5D%2CxPower%5By%2C2%5Dz%7D%2C%7BxyPower%5Bz%2C2%5D%2C1%2BPower%5Bx%2C2%5DPower%5Bz%2C2%5D%2CPower%5Bx%2C2%5Dyz%7D%2C%7BxPower%5By%2C2%5Dz%2CPower%5Bx%2C2%5Dyz%2C1%2BPower%5Bx%2C2%5DPower%5By%2C2%5D%7D%7D%2C-1%5D%7B%7B0%2C-z%2C-y%7D%2C%7B-z%2C0%2C-x%7D%2C%7B-y%2C-x%2C0%7D%7DDivide%5B1%2CSqrt%5B1%2BPower%5Bx%2C2%5DPower%5By%2C2%5D%2BPower%5Bx%2C2%5DPower%5Bz%2C2%5D%2BPower%5By%2C2%5DPower%5Bz%2C2%5D%5D%5D), the following matrix has complex eigenvalues.

[image]

Symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues, so I’m not sure what I’m failing to understand. The matrix is the shape operator of the hypersurface $f(x,y,z) = (x,y,z,xyz)$. I don’t see why this manifold would have complex-valued principal curvatures.

Comment: Does Wolfram output TeX? If so, please replace the screenshot

Comment: Are you sure it is giving you complex eigenvalues? May be it simply applies Cardano's formula? That formula needs complex cube roots even when all the zeros are real.

Comment: This is not a matrix, but a matrix-valued function.  Have you told Wolfram that the matrix is real?  Perhaps Wolfram fails to assume that it is Hermitian

Comment: See also [wikipedia, casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis): "[...] many algebraic numbers are real-valued but cannot be expressed in radicals without introducing complex numbers."

Comment: Actually, you can write the matrix as $cA$, where $A$ is just the matrix with entries $(0,z,y,z,0,x,y,x,0)$. Try this.

Comment: You can test my theory by plugging in random real numbers in place of $x,y,z$. The numerical values of the eigenvalues should all be real. It is just that Cardano's formula needs those cubic roots of unity when writing them in closed form.

Comment: Well, that resolved the unease I had. It's definitely applying Cardano's formula and since it returns real values for any x,y and z we plug in then that completely resolves my confusion.

Comment: Real numbers are complex. I see no contradiction here...

Comment: What are the eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0 & i\\i & 0\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @Rodrigo Surely the OP has in mind the elementary result that the eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are all real.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen And how is Wolfram going to learn that? Via telepathy?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo The comment exchange makes it clear what the nature and the origin of the OP's confusion was.

Comment: Would it have been more appropriate for me to say that I wasn't understanding why Wolfram gave me coefficients with non-zero imaginary part on the x,y and z terms? Then my question would have been properly posed? I apologize since this is precisely what I meant and I could have worded it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment exchange already revealed that the appearance of complex numbers in the formulas, the third root of unity in particular, was an artefact produced by Cardano's formula. A trigonometric way of solving a cubic equation makes it abundantly clear that the eigenvalues of this matrix are all real.

Let $A$ be the simpler matrix
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & z^2 & y^2 \\
 z^2 & 0 & x^2 \\
 y^2 & x^2 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
Your matrix is a scalar multiple of $A$, so it suffices to find the eigenvalues of $A$. The first thing to do is to calculate the characteristic polynomial
$$
\chi(T)=\det(T I_3-A)=T^3-(x^4+y^4+z^4)T-2x^2y^2z^2.\tag{1}
$$
The trigonometric method of solving a (depressed) cubic relies on the identity
$$
4\cos^3x-3\cos x=\cos 3x.\tag{2}
$$
The way to use it is to find a suitable new variable $u$ such that the original equation becomes
$$
4u^3-3u=v,\tag{3}
$$
where hopefully $v$ has absolute value $\le1$. Whenever that is the case, we can write $v=\cos\beta$ for some real angle $\beta$, and $(2)$ then implies that the solutions of $(3)$ are $u_k=\cos\frac{\beta+k\cdot2\pi}3$, $k=0,1,2.$

A comparison of $(1)$ and $(3)$ shows that we are looking for a substitution $\alpha u=T$ such that
$$
\frac{\alpha^2}{x^4+y^4+z^4}=\frac43.
$$
In other words, we want
$$\alpha=\frac2{\sqrt3}\sqrt{x^4+y^4+z^4}.\tag{4}$$
Plugging in $T=u/\alpha$ with the choice $(4)$ of $\alpha$ does yield after simple cleaning up the equation
$$
4u^3-3u=\frac{3\sqrt3 x^2y^2z^2}{(x^4+y^4+z^4)^{3/2}}.\tag{5}
$$

According to our plan we next need to verify that the right hand side of $(5)$ has absolute value at most $1$. Thankfully this is straight forward. By the AM-GM -inequality we have
$$
x^4+y^4+z^4\ge3(x^4y^4z^4)^{1/3}.
$$
Everything in sight is non-negative, so we can raise this to power $3/2$, and arrive at the inequality, valid for all real $x,y,z$
$$
(x^4+y^4+z^4)^{3/2}\ge 3\sqrt3x^2y^2z^2.
$$
This proves that the right hand side of $(5)$ is in the interval $[0,1]$, and hence the desired angle $\beta$ such that $\cos\beta=3\sqrt3x^2y^2z^2/(x^4+y^4+z^4)^{3/2}$ exists.

The eigenvalues $\lambda_k, k=0,1,2$, of $A$ are thus
$$
\lambda_k=\frac2{\sqrt3}\sqrt{x^4+y^4+z^4}\cos\frac{\beta+k\cdot2\pi}3.
$$
The eigenvalues $\Lambda_k=\gamma \lambda_k$ of the original matrix are gotten from these with the scaling factor $\gamma=xyz/(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2+1)^{3/2}.$

These are all manifestly real.